# Can't change size of types_hash_max_size

Tags: nginx, hash, nextcloud

Currently I'm trying to setup a nextcloud server with `nginx`. Now I've the following in my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/nextcloud.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;

    (...) 
    types_hash_bucket_size 8192;
    types_hash_max_size 8192;
    ssl_certificate /nextcloud/certification/nextcloud.csr;
    ssl_certificate_key /nextcloud/certification/nextcloud.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    (...)

    # logging
    access_log /nextcloud/access.log;
    error_log /nextcloud/error.log info;

}
```

And this is in my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
(...)
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 8192;

    # include all enabled servers!
    include sites-enabled/*;
    (...)
}
```

I created a soft link from `/etc/nginx/sites-available/nextcloud.conf` to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nextcloud.conf` so it should be loaded. Anyway I'm getting this error, when I'm running this command `nginx -t`:

```
2020/11/06 16:05:43 [warn] 249785#249785: could not build optimal types_hash, you should increase either types_hash_max_size: 1024 or types_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring types_hash_bucket_size
```

I'm wondering why I'm getting this although I've set it to `8192`? 
I created the as mentioned in from the answer link of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841551/ssl-handshaking-fails). So that's the command how I created the key:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout nextcloud.key -out nextcloud.csr
```

I've already tried to set `types_hash_bucket_size` and `types_hash_max_size` to `4096` but that doesn't change anything either.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you even changing these settings at all? I can't imagine any scenario where you will have such an extraordinarily huge number of MIME types defined. Delete them.

Comment: I thought that the size would be too small, due to my rsa key with 4096 bits. So I doubled this bucket size. Sorry if it sounds completely dumb, I'm a newbie in server adminstration. ;-;

Comment: You should not need either of those settings at all. And they are all well documented.

Comment: RSA key size and MIME type hash bucket sizes have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for the information